# Play Framework and Docker cache Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: docker, caching, playframework, bitbucket-pipelines

I use latest play and docker to run application, I have Bitbucket Pipelines CI system to build and deploy application automatically. Inside bitbucket build agent each time it runs sbt:dockerPublish and each time it builds from scratch. I already has sbt dependency cache in config, also I defined `build` folder (in which I suppose docker cache is located)  cache but it doesn't work:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
          - sbt
          - ivy2
          - play
          script: 
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_PASSWORD
          - sbt docker:publish
          - ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i $HANDLER_IP, --extra-vars "DOMAIN=$DOMAIN"
options:
  docker: true
definitions:
  caches:
    play: build
```

And each pipeline takes 7-10 minutes to run. My goal is to reduce that time. What can I do with docker cache? And also is there anything else I could optimize?